# Swift and Realm: Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type 'module<Realm>'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am literally copying and pasting code from the official Realm documentation for Swift - and it doesn't compile:

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#adding-objects

[image]

[image]
I am using Realm 1.0.2

The documentation is really conflicting with itself - with varying declarations of realm:

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
let realm = Realm()
let realm = try! Realm()
```

What's going on with Realm?

And what's the difference between Realm and RLMRealm ?
The first line above will compile fine - but the next two will NOT.

Comment: have you added `import Realm` ?

Comment: I have - that's not the issue. Try and take this code and see if it compiles for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am literally copying and pasting code from the [official Realm documentation for Swift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#adding-objects) - and it doesn't compile:

The code snippet shown in your screenshot is missing the parentheses needed to call the initializer of the `Realm` type. I've skimmed the documentation page you linked to, and from what I can see all uses of the `Realm` initializer correctly have their parens.

> The documentation is really conflicting with itself - with varying declarations of realm:

I'm not sure which documentation you're referring. The only form I see used in the [Realm Swift documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) is `let realm = try! Realm()`, which is the correct form to use with Realm Swift.

> And what's the difference between `Realm` and `RLMRealm`?

The Realm framework provides an Objective-C API, with the `RLMRealm` class representing the Realm file. The RealmSwift framework provides a Swift API, with the `Realm` class representing the Realm file.

> The first line above will compile fine - but the next two will NOT.

This reveals that you're using the Realm Objective-C framework from Swift (`import Realm`), rather than Realm Swift (`import RealmSwift`).

Comment: Thanks! If you do a google search for "realm swift tutorial" you will see that the first article that comes up from realm.io is entirely outdated and has led me down the wrong path. Please delete or otherwise update this article Realm people.

Comment: I've raised the issue of updating older blog posts with our team. Until we're able to do that we've added dates to such posts to provide some idea of the recency of such posts. If my answer addressed your problem, Stack Overflow etiquette indicates that you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: I would just remove the blog post entirely - there's no good use for it - had I not seen it this question would have never been posted.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to:

```
import RealmSwift
```